# Android - ImageButton Loses Pressed State When Notification Drawer is Pulled Down

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-imagebutton, onrestoreinstancestate, onsaveinstancestate

I am losing the pressed state of my `ImageButton` when the `notification` drawer is dragged down form the top.

I'm not sure why this is happening? I'm currently using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` to ensure that the `ImageButtons` state get's saved and restored.

For the most part it does it's job, the only issue I am having is when the `notification` drawer get's pulled down. Does anyone know why this is causing my `ImageButton` to lose it's pressed state and how to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way to get to detect the notification drawer is using 'onWindowFocusChanged'. This returns false when the drawer is pulled down and true when it get's pulled back up again.